# Automatically optimize texture files and materials, to be able to sculpt and paint

Tags: texturing, uv, sculpting, texture-painting

I used meshroom(photogrammetry software) to create models. Importing them into blender, I notice many texture files and every time I try to use clone in Texture Paint, Blender crashes.

How do I automatically optimized texture files and materials, to also be able to sculpt and paint?

Comment: As far as I know there is no easy way. You can try to automatically Remesh the model (in Data Properties) to reduce the polycount, unwrap the low poly model, then bake the original textures onto it at a lower resolution.